# Need distinct column names in final result set in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I am working in snowflake and got stuck very badly when I need unique columns in my final result set .

For e.g I have Table A with below information :

```
+---------+----------|
| user_id | product  |
+---------+----------|
| 1       | 1        |
| 1       | 2        |
| 2       | 1        |
| 2       | 2        |
| 3       | 2        |
+---------+----------|
```

TABLE B with below information :

```
+---------+---------- |
| user_id | Week      |
+---------+-----------|
| 1       | 2020-01-02|
| 1       | 2020-01-02|
| 2       | 2020-01-03|
| 2       | 2020-01-03|
| 3       | 2020-01-04|
+---------+-----------|
```

when I am writing the query

```
Select * from a join b on a.user_id =b.userid
```

I am getting the user_id two times because I am using the "*" but I need User_Id only one time with output as :

```
+---------+----------|---------- |
| user_id | product  | Week      |
+---------+----------|-----------|
| 1       | 1        | 2020-01-02|
| 1       | 2        | 2020-01-02|
| 2       | 1        | 2020-01-03|
| 2       | 2        | 2020-01-03|
| 3       | 2        | 2020-01-04|
+---------+----------|-----------|
```

But I am getting this:

```
+---------+----------|---------- |---------+
| user_id | product  | Week      | user_id |
+---------+----------|-----------|---------+
| 1       | 1        | 2020-01-02| 1       |
| 1       | 2        | 2020-01-02| 1       |
| 2       | 1        | 2020-01-03| 2       |
| 2       | 2        | 2020-01-03| 2       |
| 3       | 2        | 2020-01-04| 3       |
+---------+----------|-----------|---------+
```

The above is just and example ,in actual scenario i have 355 columns in Table A and 410 columns in Table B.So i can't do

```
Select a.column_name_1,a.column_name_2 ....a.column_name_355,b.column_name_1,a.column_name_2 ....a.column_name_355 
from table a join table b on a.uder_id = b.userid .
```

I have tried this but it is not working :

```
set name = (select listagg(column_name,',') as name from (
select row_number() over(order by column_name) column_id,column_name  from information_schema.columns
where table_schema='DEV'
and table_name ='table_a'
and column_name!='WEEK')
);

select $name from 
"DEV_DB"."DEV"."table_a" a inner join
"DEV_DB"."DEV"."table_b" b on a.WEEK = b.WEEK
```

Can anyone please help me !!

Comment: Replace the `*` with the columns you need.

Comment: @Larnu i can't because there are 355 columns in table a ,which is tedious job to write individual column names

Comment: There no magic "give me the columns I want" syntax, you need to tell the RDBMS what ones those are by writing it out. If it's "tedious" perhaps the real fact is that you don't *need* all those columns. Why do you have so many in the tables in the first place?

Comment: It is in _raw_area and i need to prepare the staging area by joining two tables.
I was trying to do something like this :



set name = (select listagg(column_name,',') as name from (
select row_number() over(order by column_name) column_id,column_name  from information_schema.columns
where table_schema='DEV'
and table_name ='table_a'
and column_name!='WEEK')
);




select $name from 
"DEV_DB"."DEV"."table_a" a inner join
"DEV_DB"."DEV"."table_b" b on a.WEEK = b.WEEK

Answer (score 0):

here is what you need ,if I understand correctly

```
select t.user_id , product , Week  
from table1 
join ( select user_id , max(week) week
       from tableB
       group by user_id
) t
on t.user_id = table1.user_id
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help.Can you please help me with the actual query :
select * from 
"DEV_DB"."DEV"."table_a" a inner join
"DEV_DB"."DEV"."table_b" b on a.WEEK = b.WEEK

Table a -355 columns
Table b- 410 columns

Comment: Please please help !!

Answer (score 0):

Using `JOIN USING`:

> [JOIN](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/join.html)
>
> ```
> USING( <column_list> )
> ```
>
> A list of columns in common between the two tables being joined; these columns are used as the join columns. The columns must have the same name and meaning in each of the tables being joined.
>
> To use the USING clause properly, the projection list (the list of columns and other expressions after the SELECT keyword) should be “*”. **This allows the server to return the key_column exactly once, which is the standard way to use the USING clause.**

```
CREATE TABLE tab1(user_id INT, product_id INT);
CREATE TABLE tab2(user_id INT, week INT);

-- output 4 columns
SELECT * FROM tab1 INNER JOIN tab2 ON tab1.user_id = tab2.user_id;
--USER_ID   PRODUCT_ID  USER_ID WEEK

-- output 3 columns
SELECT * FROM tab1 INNER JOIN tab2 USING(user_id);
-- USER_ID  PRODUCT_ID  WEEK
```

Comment: I do not have the Create permission on the db.Also is there any dynamic way to mention the column names

Comment: @abssab This is an example you do not need to create any table.

Comment: is there any alternate of "USING" ?

Comment: Please please help !!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the INFORMATION_SCHEMA views to help build your query instead of writing it all by hand for that many columns.

Example:

```
SELECT '"' || COLUMN_NAME || '" AS ' || '"TableA_' || COLUMN_NAME || '",'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA."COLUMNS" 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TableA'
ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION
```

outputs similar to:

```
"col1" as "TableA_col1",
"col2" as "TableA_col2",
etc..
```

Then just wrap the column list in a `SELECT` and `FROM TableA`, do the same for TableB and add your `JOIN` condition.

Comment: ...sorry I am not getting this.Can you please help me with detailed help

Comment: What part are you not getting? What details do you need? You'll need to be a bit more specific, did you try the steps above? What happened?

Comment: yes I have tried the above steps but not getting it ....
SELECT '"' || COLUMN_NAME || '" AS ' || '"TableA_' || COLUMN_NAME || '",'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA."COLUMNS" 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TableA'
ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION

can you please help me with an example